# Serialize emf file using readAsDataUrl in javascript

Tags: javascript, serialization

I am working on a project where I need to import windows files (ppt, word, visio, etc) and need to convert the emf to pngs.  I have the backend support via inkscape / php to handle the conversion, however, I have to POST to the BE using base64 encoded strings.  So my usecase:

1. POST serialized emf file to endpoint
2. base64_decode the string, save a temp emf file and png
3. Use inkscape to convert the emf to png.
4. Return base64 string of png.

The biggest issue is that I believe the original encoding of the emf file isn't correctly serializing.  Any thoughts?  And, I can't post the actual emf image as a blob to the BE.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue that I was having and to fix it, I used JSZip to convert this to data:application/zip;base64.  This encoded it properly and on the php endpoint, I decoded this into a tmp file, used inkscape to convert and returned the base64 encoded string of the newly created png.  The issue was not using file_get_contents so the string that was being encoded didn't exist.  I hope this helps someone else out there with a similar situation.